# Token usage of Content Filtered messages in Azure OpenAI Services

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-openai

When sending a message to a chat via **GetChatCompletions** as a response, I get a **RequestFailedException**. In the exception, I get an answer for which category content filter triggered, but nothing for how many tokens were used.

So my questions is: Do messages or responses that triggered the Content Filter not use tokens? If they do use tokens, how many are they using, and where can I get this information? Is the Azure OpenAI Service using Content Safety?

I tried to parse the message from the exception, but it just doesn't have that kind of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a request to the OpenAI API to check whether a given message is likely to trigger the Content Filter.

Here is the code:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            string apiKey = "YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY";  // Replace with your OpenAI API key
            string message = "message that is likely to trigger the Content Filter.";
    
            int? tokenUsage = await GetContentFilteredMessageTokenUsage(apiKey, message);
    
            if (tokenUsage != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The message used {tokenUsage} tokens.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The message did not trigger the Content Filter.");
            }
        }
    
        static async Task<int?> GetContentFilteredMessageTokenUsage(string apiKey, string message)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);
    
                var payload = new
                {
                    messages = new[]
                    {
                        new
                        {
                            role = "system",
                            content = "You are a helpful assistant."
                        },
                        new
                        {
                            role = "user",
                            content = message
                        }
                    }
                };
    
                var content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", content);
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    dynamic jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);
    
                    if (jsonResponse.message.role == "assistant" &&
                        jsonResponse.content_filtering.status == "failed")
                    {
                        return ((string)jsonResponse.message.content).Split(' ').Length;
                    }
                }
    
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output**
[image]

**Message: "The message did not trigger the Content Filter,"** it means that the content filter did not detect any issues with the provided message, and the message is considered safe.

When you use a message like Senstive Information, the content filter is likely to trigger, and the code will then report the number of tokens used.

**Answer you questions**

> Do messages or responses that triggered the Content Filter not use tokens?

Yes, messages or responses that triggered the Content Filter will still use tokens.
For example, a simple message like "This is a message that is likely to trigger the Content Filter." will use fewer tokens than a more complex message like "I am writing a blog post about the OpenAI Content Filter and I am wondering if you can provide me with more information about how it works."

> If they do use tokens, how many are they using, and where can I get this information?

To get the number of tokens used in a message, you can use the
`GetContentFilteredMessageTokenUsage`. This Method
will calculate the number of tokens used in the message by splitting the message content on whitespace.

> Is the Azure OpenAI Service using Content Safety?

Yes, the Azure OpenAI Service is using Content Safety.
Please refer to this [Azure AI Content Safety MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/content-safety/overview)